# Autocomplete Texstudio macro script

Tags: texstudio, scripts, javascript

Is it possible to use autocomplete in creating a macro script for Texstudio. The reason I need this is that I want to see what classes with what features can I reach when creating an script. For a simple instance, I have read a line using the following code(part of the code)

```
 var str = editor.text(linenumber);
```

Now I need to search inside "str" string. In a usual IDE you can find the proper function by using the autocomplete of that IDE. Such an autocomplete will find fucntion like

```
str.search(..)
```

Is it a way to be informed of such functions like "search" when writing scripts for Texstudio?

Comment: I think your question is not clear at all. Can you please put a MWE and show what you need to exactly do in that script?

Comment: For instance, one of the functions that can be reached in the script section of Texstudio is editor.search(..). I want to see if I can find this function by any kind of autocompletion.

Comment: I edited the question to be more comprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no autocompletion in the macro editor. This would require a complex code model of the scripting language. Neither do we have the resources to work on that, nor is it in the focus of the editor. TeXstudio is primarily a LaTeX editor with scripting support, not a script editor.

As a workaround, you may inspect an object at run-time. Here is an example for a method that writes all properties of an object to a new editor tab (based on the [code sample for introspection](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Scripts/#introspection)):

```
%SCRIPT
function write_properties(obj) {
    app.fileNew();
    newEditor = documentManager.currentDocument.editorView.editor;   //access the newly created document
    newEditor.setText(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).join("\n"));   //print the properties
}

obj = editor;                                                    //object to show (e.g. the current editor)
write_properties(obj)
```

Comment: However, there should be some kind of the IDE with which I can reach the classes and methods as yourself write the program. I have tried Webstorm but I'm not sure how to configure it to have the app editor cursor classes

Comment: Likely not. The script interfaces the C++/Qt classes of TXS at runtime. That means these classes are not written down anywhere as JavaScript code. I strongly doubt that any IDE is able to figure that out and reinterpret the C++/Qt classes to Javascript classes by static code analysis.

Comment: What about a better documentation of the methods which I can reach via scripting. Is there any other documentation besides the manual? I have written several working scripts. However, coding in this scripts seems to be very confusing and also very wanted.

Comment: There is no further documentation and that's on purpose (apart from the fact that we wouldn't have time for it). The methods are directly hooked to the internal C++ code. If we change something in the C++ code the scripting will change as well and that would break your scripts. The documented methods are methods we're trying to keep stable to provide a stable scripting API. Exposing everything would essentially mean that we couldn't change any internals without the risk of breaking scripts. We don't want that.